# Aws lambda timeout issue how much time it can execute in finally block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

My question is AWS lambda timeouts after 15 mins and if we use try catch finally then finally is called. So After timeout in finally how much time can lambda execute? Like for 1 min tr 3 secs?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 seconds to perform your finally block. Read more at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html